# Is there a command to move the current line to the top of the current window, similar to the Brief editor Ctrl-T?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Brief (if anyone remembers that far back) had a command (Ctrl-T) that recentered the window such that the current line moved to the top of the window. Ctrl-B recentered the window such that the current line moved to to the bottom of the window. Is there such a command in vscode?

If there is no command, is there an extension that provides that functionality?

I use vscode to write C# and C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly your request, but really close :

https://github.com/kaiwood/vscode-center-editor-window

You can centered your window with the shorcut ctr+L

There is a pull request to add an offset.

> EDIT
>
> Something that do exactly what you want :
>
> https://github.com/pmattei/place-window-vscode